# Getting pixel values of images in p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have been working on some code that is supposed to draw a dot(ellipse) on each pixel that is black. I am new to the get function, and suspect that I might have made a mistake using it. Does anyone know why my code cannot successfully "dot" the map of India?

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}
                  
window.onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("map");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10, 150000, 1800000);
}

function draw() {
  for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++){
    for (var y = 0; y < 100; y++){
      if(black(get(x,y))==255){
        ellipse(x , y, 10, 100); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
<style>

  p {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
  }

  img {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -1;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- PLEASE NO CHANGES BELOW THIS LINE (UNTIL I SAY SO) -->
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="p5js-temp-sadfsfdsad8981306098870070843.js"></script>
  <!-- OK, YOU CAN MAKE CHANGES BELOW THIS LINE AGAIN -->

  <!-- This line removes any default padding and style.
       You might only need one of these values set. -->
  <style> body { padding: 0; margin: 0; } </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="map" width="220" height="277" src="https://geology.com/world/india-map.gif" alt="The map">
  <!--<img src="https://geology.com/world/india-map.gif">-->
  <p id="area"></p> <br>
  <p id="perimeter"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I changed the code to

```js
  window.onload = function() {
  var c = canvas;
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("map");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10, 150000, 1800000);
}

                  

function draw() {


for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++){
  for (var y = 0; y < 100; y++){
  if(black(get(x,y))==255){
   ellipse(x , y, 10, 100);
  
}
}
}
  

    }
```

```css
<style> body { padding: 0; margin: 0; } </style>
</head>

<body>
<img id="map" width="220" height="277" src="https://geology.com/world/india-map.gif" alt="The map">
<!--<img src="https://geology.com/world/india-map.gif">-->
<p id="area"></p> <br>
<p id="perimeter"></p>
</body>
</html>
<style>

p{
position:absolute;
z-index:3;

}
img{
 position:absolute;
 z-index: -1;
  
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="p5js-temp-sadfsfdsad1466343293693433275.js"></script>


  <!-- This line removes any default padding and style.
       You might only need one of these values set. -->
```

However, I get a black rectangle on the map and no dots. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: you dont have an element with id "myCanvas", so `document.getElementById("myCanvas");` returns null

Comment: In p5js you don't need to get the canvas, you can reference it using `canvas`

Comment: This is a weird blend of p5.js and non-p5.js approaches to graphical programming.

Comment: I am new to javascript and p5js and used some code snippets from the internet.

Comment: Also -- what is `black()`? That isn't a p5.js function. As far as learning p5.js goes, I highly recommend Dan Shiffman's YouTube videos on the Coding Train channel

Comment: And even if `black()` works as intended because is defined somewhere else, you'd end up drawing very tall ellipses on top of every black pixel, including the names of the countries and regions; all that only if the pixel is perfectly black, which seems unlikely.

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat minor tweak of Nick Parson's excellent answer, but one that uses [pixels](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pixels) rather than `get`. It [runs almost instantly](https://editor.p5js.org/jcoleman/sketches/Za9gt3f6m), which shows that `get()` is the culprit.

```
//tweak of Code from Nick Parsons

let img;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage('india-map.gif');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  image(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  loadPixels();
  const d = pixelDensity();

  for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      const i = 4 * d*(y * d*width + x);
      const [r, g, b] = [pixels[i], pixels[i + 1], pixels[i + 2]]; // get colors
      if (r <= 80 && b <= 80 && g <= 80) { // if r g b all less than 80 then color will appear black
        noStroke();
        fill(255, 0, 0);
        ellipse(x, y, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  noLoop();
}
```

Comment: Nice fix, I didn't think of using `loadPixels()` :D

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using p5js you should use the methods and functions it has to offer. There is no need to get the canvas like you are when using p5js. p5js provides a reference to it when you type `canvas`.

At the moment you are using an image tag to display your image. Instead, you want to display the image to the canvas. You can do this by using p5's `preload` method to load the image. Then, once it has been loaded, you can reference it in your `draw` method.

Your `draw` method will constantly run on a loop. However, you don't need a loop as you only need to do your computations once. Thus you can use p5's method `noLoop()` to stop draw from looping.

Lastly, to get the color of a particular pixel you need to use `get(x, y)`. This will give you an array of red, green, and blue values. A black pixel is where all three of these values are `0`. However, your image has pixels which are not strictly black. For example, if your r g b (red, green, blue) color values are 1, 1, 1 your color would still look black. Thus, to check if a given color is black, you need to check if all these values are less than a particular number such as `80`.

If you incorporate all these ideas into your code you should end up with something like this:

```
let img;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage('india-map.gif');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  image(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  for(let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for(let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      const [r, g, b] = get(x, y); // get colors
      if(r <= 80 && b <= 80 && g <= 80) { // if r g b all less than 80 then color will appear black
        noStroke(); // remove black outline from thing we are about to draw (the ellipse)
        fill(255, 0, 0); // make the ellipse red
        ellipse(x, y, 1); // draw the ellipse at the pixle
      }
    }
  }
  noLoop();
}
```

You can find a working example [here](https://editor.p5js.org/NickParsons/sketches/lLj_4lTdY). But please note, this is for demonstration purposes. Please take the time to understand the code. Also, as we are looking at every pixel's color on the canvas using `get` this takes a LONG time to compute once ran. (consider looking at every 2nd pixel and drawing the ellipse a little larger)

Comment: Thank you for the code, but when I run it, I get an error message. It says,"SyntaxError: jdk.nashoen.internal.ir.ForNode cannot be cast to jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.Block." What does this mean?

Comment: @BobTimmon That error has nothing to do with this code but has something to do with how you are trying to use p5.js in a webpage. Using the p5.js web editor (as Nick is doing in the link) is probably a good idea when first learning it because it takes care of some of the HTML boiler-plate for you.

Comment: @BobTimmon Hi Bob, as John stated, it seems that you're trying to use p5 in a strange way. Maybe try playing around with the web editor.

Comment: 400^2 is only 16,000. If it takes that long then something must be a bottleneck. It turns out that `get` is somehwat expensive. If you first load the pixels and use `pixels` directly, the code runs almost instantly. I tweaked the code. It was too long for a comment, so I posted it as answer, but it was your idea (+1).